# Как определить тип штрих-кода по картинке?

Tags: штрихкод

мне нужно узнать, что это за тип штрих-кода.

[image: штрихкод]

Comment: Читать спецификации различных баркодов. Информация открыта и ее много. сравнивать свой баркод с шаблонами.

Comment: Вопрос либо не относится к программированию, либо не указан язык программирования и вопрос должен быть закрыт, либо непонятно чего вообще хочет автор. Так и так - закрыть.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится к программированию.

Comment: @AK Почему же? Предположу, что вопрошающему надо определять, какому декодеру передавать изображение. Тогда вопрос про алгоритм, то есть программистский.

Comment: @Arhad, а определять кто должен? «главный декодер»?

Answer (score 2):

Линейными (также называются полосковыми кодами) называются штрихкоды, читаемые в одном направлении (по горизонтали).
Наиболее распространённые линейные символики:

- EAN (EAN-8 состоит из 8 цифр, EAN-13 — используются 13 цифр)
- UPC (UPC-A, UPC-E)
- Code56
- Code128 (UPC/EAN-128)
- Codabar
- «Interleaved 2 of 5»

Линейные символики позволяют кодировать небольшой объём информации

[https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Штриховой_код](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)